# Swift generic types in protocol issue. Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have created a protocol for my services:

```
protocol SaveCoreDataObjectServiceProtocol  {
    associatedtype T

    func getPending() -> T?
    func deletePending(with completion: @escaping (ResultInfo<Bool>) -> Void)
}
```

I have a base class that will be a parent class of any child services:

```
class BaseSaveCoreDataObjectService<T: DynamicObject>: SaveCoreDataObjectServiceProtocol {

    func getPending() -> T? {

        let managedObject = try? CoreStore.fetchOne(
            From<T>()
                .where(
                    format: "%K == %@",
                    #keyPath(BaseMO.pendingToSave),
                    NSNumber(value: true))
        )

        return managedObject
    }

    func deletePending(with completion: @escaping (ResultInfo<Bool>) -> Void) {

        let managedObject = try? CoreStore.fetchOne(
            From<T>()
                .where(
                    format: "%K == %@",
                    #keyPath(BaseMO.pendingToSave),
                    NSNumber(value: true))
        )

        if let unwrappedManagedObject = managedObject {
            CoreStore.perform(
                asynchronous: { (transaction) -> Void in
                    transaction.delete(unwrappedManagedObject)
                    print("Deleted pending object id: ", (unwrappedManagedObject as? BaseMO)?.id ?? "Deleting pending object with no id issue.")
            },
                completion: { _ in
                    completion(ResultInfo.data(true))
            }
            )
        }
    } }
```

I have few service which just empty and inherited from `BaseSaveCoreDataObjectService`

```
class SaveWorkoutService : BaseSaveCoreDataObjectService<WorkoutEntity> {

}

class SaveExerciseService: BaseSaveCoreDataObjectService<ExerciseEntity> {

}
```

When I try to iterate them I get an error `Protocol type 'DynamicObject' cannot conform to 'DynamicObject' because only concrete types can conform to protocols` here:

```
func removeAllPendingCoreDataObjectsToSave() {
        let saveObjectServices = [SaveExerciseService(), SaveWorkoutService()] as [BaseSaveCoreDataObjectService<DynamicObject>]

        for saveObjectService in saveObjectServices {
            saveObjectService.deletePending { (result) in

            }
        }
    }
```

The idea is just to have basic parent service which includes some reusable function like `getPending()` `deletePending()` and etc and can return generic type.

If I change this

```
let saveObjectServices = [SaveExerciseService(), SaveWorkoutService()] as [BaseSaveCoreDataObjectService<DynamicObject>]
```

to this:

```
let saveObjectServices = [SaveExerciseService(), SaveWorkoutService()] as [SaveCoreDataObjectServiceProtocol]
```

I get this error:

```
Protocol 'SaveCoreDataObjectServiceProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

Comment: `SaveExerciseService` and `SaveWorkoutService` are different types. You can't use protocols as a replacement for inheritance in this way.

Comment: ok I got it, so simple get rid of protocols for this appropriate case, should solve the problem right?